# Allow user to choose an app to dial with in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, skype, phone-call, viber

**I found a way to let the user make a phone call via my app. However, I want the user to be able to choose the app from which to make the phone call from (Phone, Viber, Skype), similar to the social share functionality but for phone calls.**

I am using this now for direct dialing:

```
public static func callNumber(phoneNumber: String) {  
let cleanPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "01234567890").inverted)
        if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "tel://\(cleanPhoneNumber)")  {
            if UIDevice.current.model.range(of: "iPad") != nil {
                print("Your device doesn't support this feature.")
            } else {
                let application: UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
                if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
                    let mobileNetworkCode = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProvider?.mobileNetworkCode
                    if( mobileNetworkCode == nil) {
                        print(" No sim present Or No cellular coverage or phone is on airplane mode.")
                    }
                    else {
                        application.openURL(phoneCallURL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to make it work like social sharing in swift. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show the code you attempted to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is this thing called URL shemes (URI). https://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/

```
func open(scheme: String) {
  if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {
      (success) in
      print("Open \(scheme): \(success)")
    })
  }
}

open(scheme: "skype:<params>")
open(scheme: "viber:<params>")
```

Skype: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745885.aspx
Viber: https://developers.viber.com/tools/deep-links/index.html